# How to convert an integer to char?

Tags: java

I am suppose to write a program that accepts an integer from the user using the Scanner class and displays the char data type representation of it. Assume the user will only enter a number from 0 to 127. As of now I have this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ASCIICharacterMcAfooseMark {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //This should allow the user to enter a number
        System.out.print("Enter a number:");
        String str = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(input);
        //Need to get this to allow the entered number to show char value
        int num = 0 - 127;
        char c;
        c = (char)num;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

When I enter this into command prompt it lets me enter a number, but all I get is a bunch of words and then a question mark. Any help would be appreciated. I am using Notepadd++ in Java.

Edit: For 32, the char representation would be space.
Edit: For the System.out.println(input); I was going by what I saw in my teacher's powerpoint. Should I get rid of it?

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. `notepad++` has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: your `num` is always -127. You should probably store the value from `input` in there instead

Comment: What do you mean by "char data type representation"? Given an input of 32 (for example), what would be the correct "char data representation" to display in this case?

Comment: Why do you have this line System.out.println(input); ?

Comment: ***sigh*** Another ask-and-run

Answer (score 1):

> What do you mean by "char data type representation"? Given an input of
>   32 (for example), what would be the correct "char data representation"
>   to display in this case?
>
> When I enter this into command prompt it lets me enter a number, but
>   all I get is a bunch of words and then a question mark.

Not all `int`s  map to plain text `char`s.  Some of them map to spaces, some to backspaces, some to "print line feeds", some to "modem control characters".  For starters, look to positions 0-127 in the ACII table; however, Java really uses Unicode, so look to Unicode if you want to know how things happen above 127 (which includes your negative numbers).

Also, keep in mind that if you do not have a fully populated "glyph set" (the part of the font that draws to the screen, then various "code points" (the numbers that correspond to the glyphs) can't be drawn.  Typically this is resolved by many systems with a substitution glyph, which is that funky question mark you're seeing.

Comment: For 32 it would be space.

Comment: Give a man a fish, and he'll know that 32 maps to space.  Teach him how to fish, and he'll know how to find the output glyph for any input codepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Change your line:

```
int num = 0 - 127;//your num will always hold -127
```

To

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(str);//so you get integer representation of number string you just entered.
```

Notes apart:

- Perhaps here `System.out.println(input);` you are trying to print string user entered, so you might need to change it to `System.out.println(str);`
- There is an api which is specifically to read int from scanner and may be worth looking at [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at what your program is doing.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Note that `input` is a `Scanner` object.

```
System.out.println(input);
```

Here you are displaying the `Scanner` object itself. **Not** what the user entered, because that is in the variable `str`. Maybe you wanted to do this instead:

```
System.out.println(str);
```

Then this line:

```
int num = 0 - 127;
```

This just sets `num` to `-127`. What you wanted to do instead is parse whatever is in `str` into an `int`:

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're assuming the user will put a number from 0 to 127, then try it like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ASCIICharacterMcAfooseMark {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number:");
        String str = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(input);
        int num = Integer.parseInt(str);  //you weren't using the value from the input
        char c;
        c = (char)num;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 char c;
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("Enter a number:");
 int ip = input.nextInt();//<---- get integer
 c = (char)ip;// cast int value to char
 System.out.println(c);
```

if `input` is 97 `output` will be `a`

Comment: "Try this"-style answers are not useful. Say *what* you did, and more importantly, *why*. (Not to mention the *really big assumption* the code makes about the data.)